# Rendering HTML Content within Silverlight application

Tags: html, silverlight, .net-3.5, .net-2.0

In one of our application it is required to display bullet list in one of the Silverlight 2.0 container. We have decided to use HTML markup text for the same. While there are number of options available on Google like overlaying HTML div container etc., I would like to know what is the most workable way of doing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the easiest will be to use some 3-rd party solution. For example, Telerik has an HtmlPlaceholder that allows you to display html pages inside Silverlight application. You can see a demo here: http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#HtmlPlaceholder/FirstLook

This is how you can use it:

```
<Grid>
    <telerik:RadHtmlPlaceholder SourceUrl="http://google.com" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a lot of trouble to display a bulleted list, you can do that in native Silverlight

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/OrderedList_Silverlight.aspx

Otherwise, you can do this:

[Blend HTML and Silverlight controls together](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/02/15/using-windowless-silverlight-controls-to-blend-html-and-silverlight-elements.aspx)

Which is what I think you are alluding to in your question

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to have clickable hyperlinks, take a look at this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/delay/archive/2007/09/10/bringing-a-bit-of-html-to-silverlight-htmltextblock-makes-rich-text-display-easy.aspx