# Printing html formatted text in Silverlight 4

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, printing

How i can print the html formatted text in the silvelight 4 API.

Comment: More detail is required here before we can answer. What have you tried? Can you post the code?

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search provided the following page:

[Rendering HTML Content within Silverlight application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172278/rendering-html-content-within-silverlight-application)

The chosen answer suggests using A 3rd party tool called Telerik.

Telerik has an HtmlPlaceholder that allows you to display html pages inside Silverlight application.

You can see a demo here: [Telerik Demo](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#HtmlPlaceholder/FirstLook)